# Distinction Between Foundation Helpers and Support Helpers

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

In Laravel 5, there are now **two** `helpers.php` files

```
"files": [
    "src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php",
    "src/Illuminate/Support/helpers.php"
],
```

Is there any logical distinction between what's a foundation helper and what's a support helper?  i.e. if I was a Laravel core developer, how would I decide which file my new helper function belonged in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The foundation helpers file is for functionality directly related to the framework, like shortcuts for popular methods such as `get()` instead of `$router->get()` or `Route::get()`. You'll notice that of 35 functions (currently), almost all have variations of `return app(...)` or other similar IoC container calls.

The support helpers file is for small functions that improve php but are for the most part not really related to Laravel per se. That includes all of the `str_` and `array_` functions, for instance - functions that could just as well have been a part of the php standard library, and do not rely on the framework to work.